# OOPS design pattern to avoid binary dependency on size change

Tags: c++, oop

Sample

```
class A
{
 public:
   int i;
}; // A.h and defined in project libA.vcxproj (libA.dll)
```

Now I'm using class A in multiple places at various projects as below. Apporox 100 projects.

```
#include "A.h"
class UseA
{
   public:
    A *a;
    UseA(){
        a = new A();
    }
    ~UseA() {delete a;}
}
```

My problem is whenever I add a member variable to class A I will have to build all the projects (~100) as the size of the class A has been changed and building 100 project is time consuming.

I would like to know if there is a design pattern that will avoid building so many projects on size change of a single class. Also I have many classes like class A defined in libA.vcxproj.

Comment: One possible starting point: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm

Comment: _'if there is a design pattern ...'_ Yes, it's called the pimpl idiom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B) idiom. Something like

```
class A
{
public:
   A();
   ~A();
   int get() const;
private:
   class impl;
   std::unique_ptr<impl> impl_;
};

// in a.cpp

class A::impl
{
public:
   int i;
};

A::A() : impl_(new impl())
{
}

A::~A() {}

int A::get() const { return impl_->i; }
```

Comment: IIRC you need to provide `A`'s destructor for `unique_ptr` to work with an incomplete type.